# View added or removed technical debt by developer or group of developers

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.3, technical-debt, sonarqube-web

We are having a big team of developers which are working on multiple project in same code base, we want to see technical debt increased or decreased by each project team.  I believe at present there are no such facility in sonar  , do we have any such plugin or other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do with this is to create [Views](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/portfolio-management/) of their projects.

Comment: Hi Ann , I want to send a report of what and who added new tech debts , and we are having a huge team and big product, so before we go to production we need to resolve all tech debts introduced at least in current release

Answer (score 0):

In 5.3 the UI is improved so that you should be able to select a particular module or sub-module and view the technical debt of that specific area of your code. As long as you have a decent degree of code ownership you should be able to break down your technical debt, somewhat manually I guess, in that manner.

Comment: I want to send a report of what and who added new tech debts , and we are having a huge team and big product, so before we go to production we need to resolve all tech debts introduced at least in current release